# How to handle redirect in JavaScript For Windows 8 App?

Tags: javascript, http, windows-8, httprequest, http-redirect

I am trying to develop a Windows 8 App in which I need to login to a server but after login I get HTTP redirect response 302 and I need to redirect to this link (Location header) with cookies set in header. Seems like WinJS.xhr is unable to handle HTTP redirect. Is there any way in which I can control my requests and handle redirects also ? My language of preference for Windows App development is JavaScript.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use XHR in cases when you need to authenticate, for that you have the WebAuthenticationBroker. You can find an example [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122/view/Discussions).